# how to debug error "pythonw.exe has stopped working"

Tags: python, spyder

I am working on a code that analizes some data.
Data are loaded sequentially in a for loop and analized.
At some point I get the following message

[image]

Thi happens every time with different data... for example the first time while analizing the file 31, then analyzing the file 2

```
('Found ', 310, ' files')
Analyzing file:  0
Analyzing file:  1
Analyzing file:  2
Analyzing file:  3
Analyzing file:  4
Analyzing file:  5
Analyzing file:  6
Analyzing file:  7
Analyzing file:  8
Analyzing file:  9
Analyzing file:  10
Analyzing file:  11
Analyzing file:  12
Analyzing file:  13
Analyzing file:  14
Analyzing file:  15
Analyzing file:  16
Analyzing file:  17
Analyzing file:  18
Analyzing file:  19
Analyzing file:  20
Analyzing file:  21
Analyzing file:  22
Analyzing file:  23
Analyzing file:  24
Analyzing file:  25
Analyzing file:  26
Analyzing file:  27
Analyzing file:  28
Analyzing file:  29
Analyzing file:  30
Analyzing file:  31

Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting



Kernel died, restarting




runfile('C:/Users/Gab/pipeline.py', wdir='C:/Users/Gab')
('Found ', 310, ' files')
Analyzing file:  0
Analyzing file:  1
Analyzing file:  2

Kernel died, restarting
```

I am using python 2.7 and spyder... do you have any clue on how to debug this error? I don't get any console message...

Comment: You need to provide more details and also this is more of debugging question. How big are the files? Are you holding file content in memory? It may be that you are running out of memory or hitting any exceptions? Try to  debug using pdb then you can set a breakpoint at different points and can narrow down the issue.

Comment: Hi, no I am not running out of memory...I check Windows Task Manager...I will try to debug using pdb... never used before.... I will try